Ubuntu server not wanting to load after first prompt (first setup)
loads up and opens to the selection menu I click on try Ubuntu or install then it just shows an underscore blinking and nothing happens. this is on an older laptop but this seems to be off.

Looks like one of: corrupt boot medium, mismatched architecture, errors in your boot medium creation procedure, not setting the BOOT flag on the partition, or something else.  The boot process cannot find  any Linux kernel to load.

Does this answer your question? My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?
